# How to I conditionally format a cell based on a range of cells being blank?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[Worksheet Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PlIR.png)

I'm trying to set a fill on `L2` if `M2:W2` is blank. If there is anything in `M2:W2`I don't want the format to trigger.

In the attached image `P2` has an "x" in it and yet the formatting is triggering.

I also need the format to apply to all subsequent rows. i.e. the sam formatting should apply on row 2, 3, 4 and so on, but relative to their own row. i.e if their own row between `M to W` is blank, the format should apply.

I'm sure this is easy and I've just been starting at a screen too long today.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the column you want to conditionally format, (ex: `L2:L10`)
2. Add conditional formatting with the following formula:

   =COUNTA(M2:W2)=0

And you're done

Comment: @L23P - if this solution works for you, then you should mark the answer as correct

Comment: Sorry thought I did!